# How to create a rasterbrick from netCDF?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I want to create a rasterbrick from a netCDF file. I checked some of the basics and the process appears to be straightforward (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWy_jGZo2oc).

However, when 'bricking' my netCDF file, the dimensions of rows, columns and layers get swapped. Even when I manually define them.

```
# load libraries
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

# Load Outflow file
ncfname = "C:/Users/stijn/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Thesis/Rscripts/Outputs/swit.nc"
swit = nc_open(ncfname)

print(swit)

[     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float SWIT[time,y,x]   
            units: m/hr
            missing_value: -9999
            _FillValue: -9999

     3 dimensions:
        time  Size:2904
            units: days since 2018-12-01 00:00:00
        y  Size:127
            units: Meter
        x  Size:147
            units: Meter]
switbrick <- brick(ncfname, nrows = 127, ncols = 147, nl = 2904)

switbrick

[class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 127, 2904, 368808, 147  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.04166667, 5  (x, y)
extent     : -0.02083333, 120.9792, 6615598, 6616233  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : directory/something/swit.nc 
names      : X603301.87, X603306.87, X603311.87, X603316.87, X603321.87, X603326.87, X603331.87, X603336.87, X603341.87, X603346.87, X603351.87, X603356.87, X603361.87, X603366.87, X603371.87, ... 
x (Meter)  : 603301.87, 604031.87 (min, max)
varname    : SWIT ]
```

The dimensions should be as stated, although they are not. What causes this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the file has an unusual order, starting with `time` instead of ending with it. You can use the `dims` argument to correct for that (it seems that this is not documented).

Try

```
library(raster)
ncfname = "C:/Users/stijn/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Thesis/Rscripts/Outputs/swit.nc"
switbrick <- brick(ncfname, dims=c(3,1,2))
```

The additional arguments you provided (nrow, ncols, nlayers) are not considered when creating an object from file.

Comment: Many thanks! This solves the problem perfectly. Good to know!

Comment: @Stijn you need to accept the right answer to your question if it works for you. That is how others may note this post is responded.

Comment: @Majid Thanks for the heads-up! I tried to give the answer kudo's, but it didn't accept that since my reputation is still below 15. I figured the acceptance wouldn't work either, but I now see that it does.